# Ansible set_fact doesn't change the variable value

Tags: shell, ansible

Scenario ansible-playbook is called with passed in extra var:

```
-e my_var=init_value
```

Then in a role code the value is supposed to change via set_fact call (variable other_var value is "new_value"):

```
set_fact: my_var: {{ other_var }}
```

This results in a nice output supposedly confirming alteration:

```
{"ansible facts": {"my_var": "new_value"}}
```

However echoing the variable after changing it shows the old value:

```
echo {{ my_var }}
-> "echo init_value"
```

To add to that, when I set two variables in the above example:

```
set_fact: my_var: {{ other_var }}
set_fact: new_var: {{ other_var }}
```

The new_var is set properly.

Is the variable in some way immutable? How to use the set_fact to update the variable's value?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `set_fact` module effectively adds another host fact, ie. "a fact discovered about the system". From the documentation (http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) you can see that those facts have low priority, and will be overridden by extra-vars and various other things.

This can be confusing because using `set_fact` can make it seem like you are changing the value of the variable at that point, but maybe the name is the key to understanding - it's not 'set_variable', it's 'set_(host)fact', and host facts **have low precedence**. Precedence is more important than the order in which the value is assigned.

One workaround if you want to supply a value via extra-vars that gets overwritten later would be to reassign that extra-vars value to **a different variable** via `set_fact` at the start of your playbook, and then reassign that new variable later using set_fact again. Since they're at the same precedence level, the 'overwrite' should work as you would expect.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I believe I solved it similarly as you suggest: I've defined a new role, with set of facts, as a dependency to the task that wished to customize the values. Thanks to that, two roles may reuse third role code, just changing values.

Comment: I will also accept this answer as it describes why a "fact" is immutable, despite order of operations suggesting it could be.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, this aspect of Ansible is pretty confusing - precedence is the key here.

Answer (score 5):

Command line variables have the highest precedence of all variable types. Anything you define on the command line will override any other definitions of that variable.

Documentation on variable precedence in Ansible is here https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable That lists all the other places you could put your initial/default value.

Comment: Hi, true, but once passed in via command line, is the value immutable? Shouldn't "set_fact" update it (as extended output from that module suggests)?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. My interpretation of the docs is that a command line var is not truly immutable -- but it might as well be, because no other way of setting the value can override it. If you look at the `get_inject_vars` method in the source of ansible/lib/ansible/runner/__init__.py (https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/be4dbe76b9fbdd7e377f0d0c3ace61fa6e855e04/lib/ansible/runner/__init__.py), you can see how they set up the vars with the command line last/highest priority. Maybe a request for clearer docs would be good?

Comment: These seem to be two different things: setting the variable value, taking into consideration precedence (e.g. default loses, group vars are somewhere in between, cmd line triumps all) is one thing, whereas performing overwriting in playbooks, roles, tasks of defined variables is another - it happens after the gathering facts part. Now, even the name suggests mutability: "extraVars".