# Is there any way we can change the value of variables defined under group_vars/all

Tags: ansible

I have a variable defined in `group_vars/all` file in ansible.

```
overlay:True
```

I need to check the kernel version in playbook and set the above varibale to false if kernel version is less than 4. Can this be done in ansible.
If Yes, I would like to know the steps/ansible module .

Comment: Yes, it can be done.

Comment: @techraf Please could you tell the module that I should use for the same.

Comment: What module would you use to set any other value?

Comment: I know about set_fact.
But then I came across this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27038553/ansible-set-fact-doesnt-change-the-variable-value
whch says there is no straight forward way to do the work

Comment: Have you tried or do you just read things here and there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable

> In 2.x, we have made the order of precedence more specific (with the
>   last listed variables winning prioritization):
>
> - role defaults [1]
> - inventory file or script group vars [2]
> - inventory group_vars/all
> - playbook group_vars/all
> - inventory group_vars/*
> - playbook group_vars/*
> - inventory file or script host vars [2]
> - inventory host_vars/*
> - playbook host_vars/*
> - host facts
> - play vars
> - play vars_prompt
> - play vars_files
> - role vars (defined in role/vars/main.yml)
> - block vars (only for tasks in block)
> - task vars (only for the task)
> - role (and include_role) params
> - include params
> - include_vars
> - set_facts / registered vars
> - extra vars (always win precedence)

`set_fact` has the second higher precedence. So vars set by `set_fact` should be able to override group vars.